# Statically resolve HttpContext/HttpRequestMessage in Azure Functions from external library

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions

I need to access the current active `HttpContext` or `HttpRequestMessage` in Azure Functions.

I'm trying to achieve this from an external referenced library, without having to pass `HttpRequestMessage` as a parameter to the invoked method.

Hopefully this is possible in Azure Functions, or at least trying to access the ASP.NET Core `HttpContext` which I'm easily able to access from anywhere using `IHttpContextAccessor` (in my ASP.NET Core project).

Not sure if ASP.NET Core `HttpContext` is working in Functions.

Comment: Have you tried to test your code with Azure Functions or encounter any errors?

Comment: I tried creating a new Azure Function in Azure Portal, tried to import "Microsoft.AspNetCore.All": "2.0.0" but upon "using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;" I get this error: "The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)". I also read somewhere that Functions doesn't support HttpContext...

Comment: What version of Functions are you using - the preview .NET Core version?

Comment: I simply created a new Function in Azure Portal. I think it is set to .NET Core by default? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, accessing global http context/state isn't possible or even recommended. You should really only be operating on the HttpRequest/HttpRequestMessage that is passed to your function, passing that on to other helpers/libraries as needed.

Any global/static information that you might try to access wouldn't be reliable and might change in the future, based on our internal function execution model.

Comment: Thanks Mathew.  I'm re-writing an old .NET infrastructure to .NET Core, which includes a log module. This log module grabs every piece of relevant information upon any exception raised: network info, process info, host info (cpu/memory/os etc) and more, including HttpContext (basically: post/get parameters, client ip, user agent, full page path and more). I allow each consumer (project) to reference this infrastructure library and register to handle an exception event (in case of internal library exception) or use Logs.Write(ex) in case of exception raised in the referencing project. 1/2

Comment: In ASP.NET projects I'm allowed to grab all exceptions in global.asax and easily resolve the current HttpContext to fetch HTTP information. In ASP.NET Core I had to use IHttpContextAccessor but it finally worked out great. What can I do in Azure Functions to enable this architecture? For exceptions I'm catching explicitly I can pass "HttpRequestMessage" to Logs.Write() (although passing it every time is annoying), but what about internal errors caught inside Logs, how can I resolve the current HTTP session values? Thanks a lot. 2/2